# Filling Null values based on pivot table

Tags: python, data-science, pivot-table

My dataset has missing values in GarageYrBlt, which I would like to fill based on YearBuilt. How can I do it?

Below is pivot table for garageYrBlt based on yearblt:

pivot1

| YearBuilt | GarageYrBlt |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1976 |
| 1 | 1970 |
| 2 | 1996 |
| 3 | 1977 |
| 4 | 1977 |
| 5 | 2006 |
| 6 | 1957 |
| 7 | 1957 |
| 8 | 1965 |
| 9 | 1947 |

```
##### missing = df['GarageYrBlt'].isnull()
##### df_test.loc[missing,'GarageYrBlt'] = df_test.loc[missing,'YearBuilt'].apply(lambda x:pivot1[x])
```

but it says key error, how do I overcome this?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what the actual data (i.e. not the pivot table) looks like?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/code/arunayyappan3936/house-price-prediction/data